Trying to concatenate a row and variable columns
I'm trying to concatenate a static row and column data that is variable.   In Column A1 is Job Roles.  So in A2 the value is "Security Analyst", in A3 the value is "Security Engineer", In A4, the value is "Incident Responder"....   In Column B1 is Job Levels.  So in B2, is the value "1", in B3, the value is "2", in B4, the value is "3", in B5, the value is "Manager"...
The intent is to concatenate so that the outcome is will create "Security Analyst 1", "Security Analyst 2" "Security Analyst 3", then "Security Analyst Manager", and so on. The process would repeat with "Security Engineer 1", "Security Engineer 2", "Security Engineer 3" and then "Security Manager".
If anyone can help me figure this out - I'd be grateful.

Looks like you are trying to accomplish something like this, if so one could try the following formula:


=TOCOL(A2:A4&" "&TOROW(B2:B5))


